# Config and Run Ant from shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, ant

I want to build my project with Ant(1.8) from terminal(I use ubuntu) and want to know following when my shell script is run.
1. How to set Ant_Home ? Not setting the path in bashrc or any other location, my script requires to set the Ant which is used to build the project. (it is because, some projects are run with Ant 1.7.)

2. How to run couple of build.xml files sequentially (one after another if previously run build file is successfull) in my script. Moreover, let me know how I can pass parameters from terminal to the shell script so that the Ant home can be changed.
3. How my shell script know whether the build is successful in order to execute later commands.

EDIT: My expected shell script will be like this.I am very new to writing scripts and looking for something like below.

```
ANT_HOME = {#exact ant home path here or value passed from terminal at run time}
ANT_BUILD_XML_FILE_1 #Define the build xml file. This values should be taken from the terminal inputs  
ANT_BUILD_XML_FILE_2 #this values should be taken from the terminal inputs  
set ANT_HOME #This line will load or call the ant home
ant build -buildfile ANT_BUILD_XML_FILE_1 # run the ant build file
if(#above build is successfull)
ant build -buildfile ANT_BUILD_XML_FILE_2 #run the 2nd build file.

if(#above build 2 is successful) 
#some other command
echo"projects and jars built successfully"
```

Comment: you can set ANT_HOME with a simple `export`, and to answer your latter questions - YES, ant will return the exit code of a task/tasks to the `$?` variable, which you can use for validation in your script.

Anyways, some code snippets of what you have in mind will help us help you with the shell script.

Comment: @Dragan. Thank you very much for you attention. My question is updated with what is expected from the shell script.

Comment: `{#exact ant home path here or value passed from terminal at run time}` by this, did you mean read as user input from the LUI? Like typing in the locations yourself when you start the script?

Comment: @Dragan, Yes sir, read as user input.  Or, without getting user input is enough for ant home: straight forward, path is set in script file  like ANT_HOME = /myLibs//apache-ant-1.8.2 . Setting the path can be as a user input or directly set the value in file. It doesn't matter. But most concern is setting the path for ant build files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this also is pseudocode, sort of...

`export ANT_HOME=/path/to/ant #this will export the path variable for this session`

or if you want to read it as input

```
read ANT_HOME; export ANT_HOME
read buildXml1; read buildXml2
echo "Building"
ant build -buildfile $buildXml1  #You now have ant command available

antReturnCode=$?

echo "ANT: Return code is: \""$antReturnCode"\""

if [ $antReturnCode -ne 0 ];then

    echo "BUILD FAILED"
    exit 1;
else

    echo "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
fi
```

and so on with the validations...

A peace of advice also, if I may. If you plan on building such a script for usage you must amp up your game with some tutorials before you do so.